# In R, How can I replace ambiguous characters in string with all options for the ambiguity returning a vector of possible outputs?

Tags: r, string, replace, str-replace, stringr

Here is the the problem I'm trying to solve.

```r
#Original String
#Where ! is a ambiguous character which represent 2:n different characters. Here i assume it stands for either "1" or "2". 
I also have multiple ambiguity characters e.g. "?" = "3" or "4".

"A!!C!!D?"

#I want to know all forms a disambiguated string could take.

I.e, in this case .!!.!!.? could produce
4*4*2 = 32 possibilities. 

#I want a function to return all possibilities as a vector.

#e.g. desired return
c("A11C11D3", "A11C12D3", "A11C21D3", "A11C22D3",
  "A12C11D3", "A12C12D3", "A12C21D3", "A12C22D3",
...
)
```

Is there a simple function I'm missing which does this or do I need to build it from the ground-up with gsub or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to split the string, replace the ambiguous characters with their possible values, generate the possible combinations and paste back together.

```
mystring <- "A!!C!!D?"

lapply(strsplit(mystring, ""), function(x) {
  res <- lapply(x, function(y)
    switch(y,
      "!" = 1:2,
      "?" = 3:4,
      y)
    )
  do.call(paste0, expand.grid(res))
})

[[1]]
 [1] "A11C11D3" "A21C11D3" "A12C11D3" "A22C11D3" "A11C21D3" "A21C21D3" "A12C21D3" "A22C21D3" "A11C12D3" "A21C12D3" "A12C12D3" "A22C12D3"
[13] "A11C22D3" "A21C22D3" "A12C22D3" "A22C22D3" "A11C11D4" "A21C11D4" "A12C11D4" "A22C11D4" "A11C21D4" "A21C21D4" "A12C21D4" "A22C21D4"
[25] "A11C12D4" "A21C12D4" "A12C12D4" "A22C12D4" "A11C22D4" "A21C22D4" "A12C22D4" "A22C22D4"
```